# convert rows to columns in Access

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, pivot

I have read many question on Stack Overflow related to my problem, but I don't think they quite address my problem. Basically I download a XML dataset with lots of data, and inserted that data into my MS Access database. What I want to do is convert the data so that some specific rows become columns.

Now I can probably do this manually in code before inserting the data to database, but that would require lots of time and change in code, so I'm wondering if its possible to do this with MS Access.

Here's how my table basically looks, and how I want to convert it.

The index is not so relevant in my case

```
[Table1]               =>              [Table1_converted]

[Index]  [Name]   [Data]  [NameID]      [NameID]  [AA]    [BB]    [CC]    [DD]   
 1        AA       14      1             1         14     date1    64      61   
 2        BB(date) 42      1             2        15+19   date2   67+21   63+12
 3        CC       64      1             3          9              10    
 4        DD       61      1             4                date4     1      87
 5        AA       15      2                 
 6        BB(date) 35      2
 7        CC       67      2        
 8        DD       63      2
 9        AA       9       3
10        CC       10      3
11        AA       19      2                
12        BB(date) 20      2
13        CC       21      2        
14        DD       12      2
15        BB(date) 83      4
16        CC       1       4
17        DD       87      4
```

Forgot to mention that, the Values under the column [Name] are not really AA BB CC.
They are more complex then that. AA is actually like "01 - NameAA", without the quotation mark.

Forgot to mention one important element in my question, if the [Name] ex. AA with same [NameID] exists in table, then the [Data] should SUM up those two values. I have edited the tables, on the converted table i have written ex. 15+19 or 35+20 which only illustrates which values are summed up.

One more edit, hopefully the last. One of the [Name] BB has a Datetime type in [Data].
The NameID can be whichever, does not matter. So i need a query which does an exception on [Name] BB when its summing up, so that it does not sum it up like it does to every other [Name]s [Data]. Places where date is written multiple times for same [Name] and [NameID], it is always the same.

Comment: Looks like you want a pivot table.

Comment: Access SQL (Access) and T-SQL (SQL Server) are very different. Is [Table1] a native Access table? If so, then the 'sql-server' tag should be removed from this question.

Comment: removed the sql tag. I chose it thinking it was a generic term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this in Access, all you need to do is

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum([Data]) AS SumOfData
SELECT [NameID]
FROM [Table1]
GROUP BY [NameID]
PIVOT [Name]
```

**edit re: revised question**

To handle some [Name]s differently we would need to assemble the results (`Sum()`s, etc.) first, and then crosstab the results

For test data in [Table1]:

```
Index  Name  Data        NameID
-----  ----  ----------  ------
    1  AA    14               1
    2  BB    2013-12-01       1
    3  CC    64               1
    4  DD    61               1
    5  AA    15               2
    6  BB    2013-12-02       2
    7  CC    67               2
    8  DD    63               2
    9  AA    9                3
   10  CC    10               3
   11  AA    19               2
   12  BB    2013-12-02       2
   13  CC    21               2
   14  DD    12               2
   15  BB    2013-12-04       4
   16  CC    1                4
   17  DD    87               4
```

the query

```sql
TRANSFORM First(columnData) AS whatever
SELECT [NameID]
FROM
    (
            SELECT [NameID], [Name], Sum([Data]) AS columnData
            FROM [Table1]
            WHERE [Name] <> 'BB'
            GROUP BY [NameID], [Name]
        UNION ALL
            SELECT DISTINCT [NameID], [Name], [Data]
            FROM [Table1]
            WHERE [Name] = 'BB'
    )
GROUP BY [NameID]
PIVOT [Name]
```

produces

```
NameID  AA  BB          CC  DD
------  --  ----------  --  --
     1  14  2013-12-01  64  61
     2  34  2013-12-02  88  75
     3  9               10    
     4      2013-12-04  1   87
```

Comment: OMG, that was a really nice and simple solution. It did exactly what i needed. Thanks mate.

Comment: Hi, i was a little hasty with my question. There is one more element i forgot to add to my question. It is basically if i have multiple Names example AA with same NameID example 1. I would like to them to be summed up together so that the converted table only shows the SUM of all AAs with same NameID.
Ill change the question to visually show what i mean.

Comment: @Mana That's easy, we just change the query to use `Sum()`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, testing it now.

Comment: Hi again, so i have tested now your solution, and it does work, but there is one small problem. The thing is, some of the [Data] contains Datetime type, don't ask my why. And i know for certain that only the [Name] BB contains them, and some are null whatever the [NameID]. So i was wondering if it is somehow possible to filter so that only the [Name] BB containing the Datetime under [Data] is not summed up? –  Mana 7 mins ago

Comment: Thank you again, testing it now.

Comment: This seems to be what i'm looking for. But what if i had another [Name] that needed not to be summed up. Can i simply write, 
......
WHERE [Name] <> 'BB' AND [Name] <> 'XX'
......
......
WHERE [Name] = 'BB' AND [Name] = 'XX' ??

Comment: You could do something along those lines, or you could just do `WHERE [Name] NOT IN ('BB','XX')` for the first part and `WHERE [Name] IN ('BB','XX')` for the second part.

Comment: Thanks mate. I have now completed the testing, and it seems to be works perfectly. Have also tested if i want to exclude more vars, and that works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...in sql query may be it is your answer

```
   SELECT NameID , [AA] as AA,[BB] as BB,[CC] as CC,[DD]  as DD     
        FROM        
        (
            SELECT Name,Data,NameID FROM Table1
        )PivotData

        PIVOT
        (
            max(Data) for Name in ([AA],[BB],[CC],[DD])     
        ) AS Pivoting
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the square brackets[ ] just indicate that this is a column. The original name is without the square brackets [ ]

Comment: Could you check my update/edit of my question and tell me if this still applies?

Comment: then use [01 - NameAA]  in palce of [AA] and same as rest of all fields

Comment: I have gone with Gord Thompsons solution. it was really simple and easy to use. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to this

1) Take all your Table1 as it is in SQL Server

2) Then run following query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from [Table1]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT countryid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                select NameID, Name 
                from Table1 cc                
            ) T 
            pivot 
            (
                max (Name)
                for languagename in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Could you check my update/edit of my question and tell me if this still applies?

Comment: I have gone with Gord Thompsons solution. it was really simple and easy to use. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ([Index] INT,[Name] CHAR(2),[Data] INT,[NameID] INT) 

INSERT INTO @Table1
VALUES
 (1,'AA',14,1),              
 (2,'BB',42,1),            
 (3,'CC',64,1),             
 (4,'DD',61,1),             
 (5,'AA',15,2),                
 (6,'BB',35,2),
 (7,'CC',67,2),        
 (8,'DD',63,2),
 (9,'AA',9,3),
(10,'CC',10,3),
(11,'BB',83,4),
(12,'CC',1,4),
(13,'DD',87,4)

SELECT [NameID] , ISNULL([AA], '') AS [AA], ISNULL([BB], '') AS [BB]
        , ISNULL([CC], '') AS [CC], ISNULL([DD], '') AS [DD]
FROM  
    (
    SELECT NAME, DATA, NAMEID
    FROM @Table1
    )q
    PIVOT
        (
        SUM(DATA)
        FOR NAME
        IN ([AA], [BB], [CC], [DD])
        )P
```

**Result Set**

```
NameID  AA    BB    CC  DD
1       14    42    64  61
2       15    35    67  63
3       9           10  
4             83    1   87
```

Comment: The result values under DD doesn't seem to be correct, in your case, or was it just a misspelling?

Comment: @Mana ops its not incorrect but its the table format let me fix it they are pushed under CC but answer is definitely correct.

Comment: Could you check my update/edit of my question and tell me if this still applies?

Comment: @Mana if you dont want nulls to be shown just use the ISNULL function wait I will update my answer have a look then.

Comment: @Mana Have a look now I have updated my answer replaced nulls with empty string and formatted it. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Yep I have read your Question in that case you will need to concatenate dynamically the valuez from Name Column to be used as Pivot Column then you should go with the way @Dhaval has suggested.

Comment: So, i have tried your solution, but i don't seem to get it working for me. So ill go with Gord Thompsons solution. it was really simple and easy to use. But thanks for your effort though.

Comment: Not a problem mate, im glad you have found a solution :)